# Maven does not recognize persistence.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven

Recently recognized that in my project `mvn install` command does not recognize persistence.xml file.

I wrote hodor tag into persistence.xml. IDE gives an error. Meanwhile i try to compile project with `mvn install` command, there is no error and gives build success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/OracleDS</jta-data-source>
      <hodor>hodorhodorhodor</hodor>
      <class>com.mycompany.MyClass</class>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Is there exist any setting or plugin to compile like persistence.xml file successfully ?

Comment: If the project get complied with Maven it's just a Eclipse configuration problem, you can check the project assembly to see if the persistence is loaded from the right directory, also you can try to click update Maven project to see if it will fix the problem... It's usual that the Maven project structure and Eclipse projects structure are not aligned for some reason... Is it a Web project?

Comment: are you using a maven plugin that test JPA configuration? otherwise maven do not check persistence.xml in standard compile phase. It's just a resorce file added to the artifact.

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy it is a web project.

Answer (score 0):

Just found answer but little exhaustive. It has done with [mojohaus maven xml plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/validation.html).

Firstly i have downloaded related .xsd file from `xsi:schemaLocation` tag.

```
<xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
```

Moved persistence_2_0.xsd into my project's resources folder.

[image]

After imported mojo's xml plugin into pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <goals>
            <goal>validate</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
      <validationSets>
         <validationSet>
            <systemId>src/main/resources/persistence_2_0.xsd</systemId>
            <dir>src/main/resources/META-INF</dir>
         </validationSet>
      </validationSets>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

At last executed `mvn xml:validate` command and given that result;

```
[ERROR] Invalid content was found starting with element 'hodor'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":non-jta-data-source, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":mapping-file, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":jar-file, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":class, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":exclude-unlisted-classes, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":shared-cache-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":validation-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":properties}' is expected.
```